# Using htmlspeciachars on output from database (MySQL), what else to consider to prevent XSS?

Tags: php, mysql, database, xss

Using htmlspeciachars on output from database (MySQL), what else to consider to prevent XSS?

Is it correct that using htmlspecialchars on output when fethcing data from database (in this case MySQL) you will prevent XSS? In this case HTML to be shown in a HTML-document? Are there anything else you should consider? I mean in which other cases could you be vulnerable for XSS?

Lets say i have a webiste where i have created a login-system, for users to post new posts, and here the users can delete these news post, but a JavaScript function is here used with a alertbox() to make sure that the user really want to delete this news, and if yes the news ID is passed through the URL by link like this:

```
echo '<a class="btn-small btn-danger" onclick="deleteNews('. htmlspecialchars($newsidfk) .')" ">Delete news</a>';
```

Javascript function:

```
//alert deleteNews
function deleteNews($newsidfk)
{
var ans = window.confirm(Are you sure you want to delete this news post?');
        if (ans == true)
        {
            window.location.href="delete.php?news_id_fk="+$newsidfk;
        }
}
```

Is there something something else i should consider to prevent XSS, or can no XSS be done here? Lets say i've have a string istead of a number, should i do some JavaScript encoding, maybe encodeURI() function?

Is it correct that using htmlspecialchars you prevent for instance script-tags, link-tags and img-tags to be run? And this is how with XSS work, because then someone can, for instance, steal users private information?

I’ve learned that you should always sanitize when displaying output from database, but what about input that are being stored into the database? Should you also sanitize this, or is it just enough to use PDO prepared statements, or something else and how to do so?

I’ve read about HTML sanitizing form this article on wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization

Answer (score 1):

Always output JavaScript literals as JSON.

```
<a class="btn-small btn-danger" onclick="deleteNews(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($newsidfk)); ?>)" ">Delete news</a>

<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, never heard of this json_encode, should include a library for this?

Comment: Should i only do this when working with a string? I mean if its just a number, i do not need to do this?

Comment: No, but your PHP should be built with [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) support.

Comment: Strictly speaking you don't *need* to if you're *certain* it's a number, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Okay, will look into this JSON when working with PHP. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct that using htmlspecialchars on output when fethcing data from database (in this case MySQL) you will prevent XSS? In this case HTML to be shown in a HTML-document? Are there anything else you should consider? I mean in which other cases could you be vulnerable for XSS?

Yes, that is sort-of correct. One part of the full story that sometimes is overlooked are the character encodings. While by default this works fairly well, it *can* be that it's with issues if you didn't check that the encodings you use on the data you put through `htmlspecialchars` is also signalled to the function itself.

E.g. if you use PHP 5.3, and you have UTF-8 encoded strings in your database and you query them as such and you use UTF-8 inside your HTML, then you should also tell `htmlspecialchars`:

```
$flags    = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401;
$encoding = 'UTF-8'

htmlspecialchars($string, $flags, $encoding);
```

Albeit if you're using PHP 5.4, UTF-8 is the default encoding and you don't need to provide it then:

```
htmlspecialchars($string);
```