# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal SELECTING MAX(streamitem_id)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, syntax-error

I'm trying to extract the MAX streamitem_id from the streamdata table but when I change the query from `SELECT streamitem_id` to `SELECT MAX(streamitem_id)` it gives me the below error.

How can I rectify this issue?

This is the error I'm getting from Firebug.

```
 SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
    [Break On This Error]   

    var current_last_status_id="<br />
```

An below the client side code

```
<?  $timestamp = "SELECT MAX(streamitem_id) FROM streamdata";
            $chant = mysqli_query($mysqli, $timestamp) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            while ($streamitem_data= mysqli_fetch_array($chant)) {

    ?>
    <script>


    setInterval(function(){
        var current_last_status_id="<?php echo $streamitem_data["streamitem_id"];?>";

           $.ajax({ type: "GET", 
                    url: "streampostinsert.php?current_last_status_id=" + current_last_status_id,  

                    dataType:"json",
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(response){
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14187452/367456

Comment: Changed it to -   `var current_last_status_id=<?php echo json_encode($streamitem_data["streamitem_id"]);?>` and still receiving the same error.

Comment: Don't see why all the relevant PHP code was removed from this, guess you're in one of those moods again hakre?

Comment: @Dale: reverted that already. This question is not able to properly recycle into something valuable I had to admit.

Comment: I see. Stop guessing now and start troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the SQL to this

```
$timestamp = "SELECT MAX(streamitem_id) AS streamitem_id FROM streamdata";
```

The error you are seeing in firefox is a javascript error, but I think the real error is that PHP is throwing a notice about undefined index streamitem_id in the middle of your javascript.

I believe you need to alias the returned value or you will have something along the lines of..

```
$streamitem_data['MAX(streamitem_id)']
```

Which is a nightmare

Comment: Still getting the same error with that.

Comment: In your question you haven't included the PHP error that's happening in the javascript, can you add it?

Comment: Undefined index: streamitem_id on line

Comment: Yea so change the SQL as I said :)

Comment: I did and still got the same Dale. Its like its not finding the output in the loop.

Comment: $timestamp = "SELECT MAX(streamitem_id) AS streamitem_id FROM streamdata";

That worked just fine. The bottom bit was unnecessary. Thank you Dale

Comment: @Dave: You should really stop with guessing and start with programming. Your comment shows that you do not even understand why this works. You will be here in not time with the next problem your run into because you need somebody else to fix it for you. That's not the intention of this website.

Answer (score -1):

try to change

```
SELECT MAX(streamitem_id) FROM streamdata
```

to

```
SELECT MAX(streamitem_id) AS streamitem_id FROM streamdata
```